# Smaller output stride and bigger atrous rates produces larger heatmaps

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

I am using DeepLabv3+ and I am running some tests. For my first run I used an `output_stride=16` and `atrous_rates=[6, 12, 18]` and in the 2nd run I used `output_stride=8` and `atrous_rates=[12,24, 36]`. Then I used tensorboard to see the results and I could notice that the heatmaps look larger and one "unit" is 4x bigger than the run with `output_stride=16`. [image]

`output_stride=16`

[image]

`output_stride=8`
I would like to know what is the reason behing this behaviour and the consequences on my mIOU metric.

regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the paper [Encoder-Decoder with Atrous Separable Convolution for Semantic Image Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00915.pdf) (3.1 DeeplabV3+ as an encoder), output_stride simply means the ratio between image input size and feature map output size (before global pooling). So change output_stride will change the output result.

just copy form [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4233).